# Will data compression produce less transaction logs?

Tags: sql-server

The data compression is now available on SQL SERVER 2008 and later. So, it will compress the data size, also the storage for this server. I wonder if it will produce less transaction logs by same operations if the table is compressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data held in the transaction log for transactions performed against compressed tables will use ROW compression (doesn't matter if you use ROW or PAGE in the table)

See the "What Happens to the Supporting Data Structures" section of the following page for reference:

[Data Compression: Strategy, Capacity Planning and Best Practices](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894051(v=sql.100).aspx)